# Why doesn't an OR operator work inside CASE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have been trying to put an **OR** operator in CASE statement but it doesn't work.

```
 Where W.Organization_ID = 
 CASE @IsAdmin OR @IsChiefEngineer 
 WHEN 1 
 THEN W.Organization_ID 
 ELSE @OrganizationID END
```

I want to check if any IsAdmin or IsChief engineer, either or they is 1 then Organization else @OrganizationID

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: The syntax you are using doesn't work with more than one variable.  Check out the answers below for a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly, just alter your case statement a bit :

```
CASE
WHEN @IsAdmin = 1  OR @IsChiefEngineer = 1 
THEN W.Organization_ID 
ELSE @OrganizationID 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as follows:

```
Where W.Organization_ID = CASE 
    WHEN @IsAdmin = 1 OR @IsChiefEngineer = 1 
        THEN W.Organization_ID 
    ELSE @OrganizationID END
```

Answer (score 0):

You should test every parameter "inside" the OR operator

```
    CASE 
       WHEN @IsAdmin = 1 OR @IsChiefEngineer = 1 
       THEN W.Organization_ID 
       ELSE @OrganizationID 
    END
```

Comment: Sorry, I  didn't pay attention to your code, this should work, but it was already answered.